# Get initialization parameter from the web.xml file. in Eclipse and Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, javaw

I am following this tutorial  http://www.javatpoint.com/config-implicit-object

This tutorial uses an file web.xml without a servelet and fill in the variables of the file "welcome.jsp" with the data of the file "web.xml"
I put all files in the same folder of Eclipse called "WebContent", but the program don't work. I am a newbie in Eclipse and JSP

WebContent/index.html

```
<form action="welcome">  
<input type="text" name="uname">  
<input type="submit" value="go"><br/>  
</form>
```

WebContent/web.xml

```
<web-app>  

<servlet>  
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>  
<jsp-file>/welcome.jsp</jsp-file>  

<init-param>  
<param-name>dname</param-name>  
<param-value>sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</param-value>  
</init-param>  

</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

WebContent/welcome.jsp

```
<%   
out.print("Welcome "+request.getParameter("uname"));  

String driver=config.getInitParameter("dname");  
out.print("driver name is="+driver);  
%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put `web.xml` into the `WEB-INF` directory. That is where the servlet container expects it, otherwise it has no effect. Putting it into `WEB-INF` also has the "side-effect" of not making the file accessible to users for download through their browser (which would be bad, as it can contain sensitive configuration information).

So the path should be `WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Thilo. I can solve the problem, but  Is it possible to create a xml file  without to have  created a servelet previously?.  I haven't created any servelet

Comment: I haven't created any servelet called <servlet-name>sonoojaiswal</servlet-name>  inside my proyect

Comment: You can pass params from web.xml to JSP using `context-param`. Those are outside of the `<servlet>` section (which you can remove).